# Get coordinates of an image

Tags: java

I have tested my code before and it seems that it was working perfectly but now my function doesn't find an image coordinates on my Windows screen (return -1,-1).

Does the JDK version make a difference? Or is there a bug in the code below?

```
public int[] foundImageCoord(String imageName) {
    try {
        // current screen capture
        BufferedImage current = createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        // image to search
        BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));

        // container
        for (int x = 0; x < current.getWidth() - icon.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < current.getHeight() - icon.getHeight(); y++) {

                // image moving in the container
                boolean matches = true;
                overloop:
                for (int x2 = 0; x2 < icon.getWidth() ; x2++) {
                    for (int y2 = 0; y2 < icon.getHeight() ; y2++) {
                        if (icon.getRGB(x2, y2) != current.getRGB(x + x2, y + y2)) {
                            matches = false;
                            break overloop;
                        }

                    }

                }
                if (matches) { // image found
                    return new int[] { x, y };
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new int[] { -1, -1 };
}
```

In my function main :

```
    WindowsBot bot;

    try {

        bot = new WindowsBot();

    while(true){

            int[] iconLocation = bot.foundImageCoord("skype/writeMessage.png");
            System.out.println("x : " + iconLocation[0] + " y : " + iconLocation[1]);

            //bot.click(iconLocation);
    }
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the console log :

```
x : -1 y : -1
x : -1 y : -1
x : -1 y : -1
x : -1 y : -1
x : -1 y : -1
```

Comment: did it stop working after you changed JDK?

Comment: Does it return -1,-1 because it never matches or because of an error?

Comment: Code not working as expected, and an empty `catch` block. First thing to try: `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: @Jack Flamp My windows computer had an upgrade and when I have used the fonction "move(x,y)" of the Robot class, their is a probleme : the cursor move to a wrong position whereas the image was found. After searching on Google I found that it could be a scale problem. And I have changed the JDK version, the cursor move correctly but I have no match with this function. My older JDK was 1,6 and now my version is 9.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have added e.printStackTrace() to the catch and it is the same.

Comment: @Ilan Don't forget to break out of the two loops after `matches = false;` You don't need to loop over the remaining items.

Comment: @MCEmperor I break as soon as "matches" equals "true" (I break with the return). When match = false,the image to search differ from the portion of the screen

Comment: @Ilan Yeah, but that is just half the optimization. You indeed return when all pixels of the given icon match the checked screen portion. But for the icon check (the two inner for loops), the same counts: when a pixel doesn't match, we don't need to walk the remaining pixels of the icon. You might just want to move the icon check to another method.

Comment: @MCEmperor thanks for your advice, I have added it and now it is much faster.

Comment: This code works fine for me. What kind of image do you use?

Comment: I use some PNG files. I use some icons like "accept call" in Skype or an image containing words (like "write a message").